# Using Grape to build a Rails API but having issues posting JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-grape

Here is my API `post`:

```
resource :service_requests do
  get do
    authenticate!
    current_company.service_requests
  end

  params do
    requires :service_request, type: Hash do
      optional :prefix, type: String
      requires :first_name, type: String
      requires :last_name, type: String
      requires :contact_email, type: String, regexp: User::EMAIL_REGEX
      requires :telephone, type: String
    end
  end

  post do
    authenticate!
    { service_request: params[:service_request] }
  end
end
```

Here is what my `json` post looks like:

```
{
  'service_request': {
    'first_name': 'Foo',
    'last_name': 'Bar',
    'contact_email': 'foo@bar.com',
    'telephone': '111-111-1111'
  }
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (795: unexpected token at '{
  'service_request': {
    'first_name': 'Foo',
    'last_name': 'Bar',
    'contact_email': 'foo@bar.com',
    'telephone': '111-111-1111'
  }
}'):
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Anyone see anything that stands out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes in your json:

```
{
  "service_request": {
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "last_name": "Bar",
    "contact_email": "foo@bar.com",
    "telephone": "111-111-1111"
  }
}
```